# Calculating the number of ‘not null’ values from a selection of fields using Calculate Field with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: python, arcgis-pro

I’m looking to use the field calculator to calculate the number of ‘NOT  NULL’ values in a subset of fields within an attribute table.

| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 | Field 5 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | Null | 1 | Null | 3 |

I have used the `sum(filter(None,Args))` Python script to calculate the sum of the fields but I also want to calculate the number of not null values.

How can I do this?

*EDIT*

This is my existing code and error message

`stack(!Signage_Adequate_Directional!,!Signage_Positive_Wording!,!Signage_Information!,!Signage_Welcome_Sign!,!Signage_Notice_Board!)`

```py
def stack(*args):  
    return len(filter(None, args))
```

[image: Screenshot of calculate field error in Arcgis Pro]

Comment: Change the `sum()` to `len()`

Comment: These are ‘integers’. The len() function calculates the length of a string.

Comment: I get the following error message when i use len instead of sum - WARNING 002858: Certain rows set to NULL due to error while evaluating python expression:   File "<string>", line 2, in stack

Comment: I seem to be allowed to calculate the length of all of the fields but not use the filter script to remove the null values before calculating the length.

Comment: Python `len()` also reports the length of a list. You haven't provided all the parameters you are using in the Question body, so it's difficult to determine what is going on. Go into Geoprocessing..  Results, click on the various trials, Copy As Python snippet and paste into an [Edit] of the Question. There's probably a half-dozen different ways to do this with lists, sets, and list comprehensions, but syntax is critical.

Comment: Calculate Field
Parameters

Input Table     test
Field Name (Existing or New)     Signage_Factors_Assessed
Expression     stack(!Signage_Adequate_Directional!,!Signage_Positive_Wording!,!Signage_Information!,!Signage_Welcome_Sign!,!Signage_Notice_Board!)
Expression Type     PYTHON3
Code Block     def stack(*args):
    return len(filter(None, args))
Updated Input Table     test
Field Type     TEXT
Enforce Domains     NO_ENFORCE_DOMAINS

WARNING 002858: Certain rows set to NULL due to error while evaluating python expression:   File "<string>", line 2, in stack

Comment: Please [edit] the question. Comments do not have enough formatting options to legibly post large code blocks.

Comment: What happens if you change your `return` statement to `return len(list(filter(None, args)))`?

Comment: I think that’s done the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One can use [sum - Built-in Functions -- Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to count, just sum quantity one (1) instead of the value itself.  For example, instead of `sum([1,2,4])` one can use `sum(1 for _ in [1,2,4])`.

Although [filter- Built-in Functions -- Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) is a built-in function, it is arguably not Pythonic in its form.  The Python documentation even states, "Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator expression...."

For this specific situation, the code block isn't necessary and a single Python expression will suffice.

```py
# Count = 
sum(1 for value in (!Field1!, !Field2!, !Field3!, !Field4!, !Field5!) if value is not None)
```